# facebook FB.login returns blank popup in Safari

Tags: facebook, oauth, safari, facebook-javascript-sdk

facebook javascript SDK is giving me a white popup when trying to login, I followed their official "how to authenticate using javascript" documentation and it works in chrome, firefox but NOT in safari or IE

any ideas?

Comment: I've been seeing this issue sporadically as well since around 7pm PDT on Mar 28, 2013. Hitting the actual FB URL for oauth, I get a 500.

Comment: unfortunatly it's a know issue at facebook, nothing we can do :(